# Generation of random numbers but controlling the count of those numbers

Tags: c

If i want to generate 0,1,2 randomly in a 2D matrix but i want to control the count of 0,1,2. Is this can be done by any inbuilt c function??(I am using C and new to programming.)

Comment: basically you ask how to get a random number from specific range ?

Comment: @Stargateur I understand it as random positions for a fixed amount of numbers.

Comment: You really think there's a builtin doing exactly what you want? How about solving the problem yourself? What would you do by hand?

Comment: I want to generate 0,1,2 but I wish 7% of the total size of matrix filled with 1 and 3% with 2 and rest 90% with 0 but this should be random

Comment: @JithinPavithran standard C only provides random integers, your comment doesn't apply here.

Comment: @jaizz so? Determine the **positions** at random!

Comment: ok thnks,that means I need to find an appropriate algorithm and no inbuilt can help??

Comment: i am using srand to seed and rand to generate

Comment: [simple and stupid example](https://ideone.com/fYLzrq)

Comment: Just fill the array with the required number repetitions of each value (in order), and then scramble them.  This is just another way of saying what @Felix suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that you have a 3x3 matrix and you want three each of 0, 1, 2.  The most practical way to do this is to fill in the matrix with the right number of numbers in a non-random way, like

```
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2 2
```

and then use a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to put them in a random order.  You will have to implement the shuffle yourself, but you can use `rand()` in the normal way in your implementation.

This works for any situation where a fixed number of fixed values need to be put into random positions within a list.

Comment: ok thnks..i will try to work it out